# Access WordPress directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hello guys your help is appreciated. I will rephrase my problem, nothing complicated.

I have a WordPress website:

- I added a new folder called demo from cPanel
  [demo folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAYDL.png)
- folder contain php file that echo test
- htaccess generated by wordpress as follows [htaccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo4rb.png)

By default, i would access the file like this
`www.example.com/demo/test,php`
and the browser will display the echo message.

I tried everything to access the directory
`- example.com/demo/`  and `www.example.com/demo/test.php`
both gives me the 404 page not found. (the error page for 404 error)
[404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gtwN.png)

I want to access the director `www.example.com/demo/` which I build a normal html website

Comment: Is the 404 error page you are seeing generated by WordPress or is this an Apache generated response? Presumably you created the `demo` subdirectory within the document root (often called `/public_html` on cPanel managed sites)? Please include the directory/file structure in your question.

Comment: yes, I created it in `public_html` folder where the main Wordpress website is installed , the 404 page is generated by Wordpress , a default page from the website that display page not found. I guess the problem is from permalink since there is no post called demo and its not reading it as a folder. I need to access it as a folder

Comment: Please edit your question with the contents of your root htaccess file. If the file is called test.php then you can't access it by simply requesting the directory without additional rules.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `RewrietOptions inherit` - what are you inheriting?

Comment: @MrWhite I don't know, it is generated by WordPress. I just want to access the directory from URL in chrome

Comment: WordPress itself should not add that `RewriteOptions inherit` directive. That might be added by your webhost, if it's being added automatically? That directive causes directives in a parent config (eg. the main server config) to be inherited - this has nothing to do with WordPress. You should not need to add anything to be able to access `/demo/test.php` (note the `.` (dot), not a `,` (comma) as in your example?) - so there would seem to be something different with your server config? (Try removing that `RewriteOptions` directive - what happens?)